# How to change domain part of active directory programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I am working on a web based application where active directory users corresponding organization units are created dynamically . However, once users are created in active directory i want to change their domain part.

Say initially i am creating user with domain test.com so i want it to be changed to online.application.com .

I investigated on it and find out that [How to programmatically add UPN Suffix in Active Directory Domains and Trusts in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716376/how-to-programmatically-add-upn-suffix-in-active-directory-domains-and-trusts-in) and implemented it as part of the code.

However, it is not making user use new domain.

Please let us know how i can make domain name changes once user is created so that even though user is created with diffrent user name his domain details can be changed.

Comment: I don't think you can change the domain for a user once it's created, as the users are created *in* the domain.  It wouldn't make much sense for a domain to have it's users' data in another domain, as otherwise how could the Domain Controller control it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the userPrincipalName attribute.  This is what the User logon name box is mapped to in ADUC.